How to use PHP pcntl_rfork?
I want to experiment with pcntl_rfork to manipulate process resources in PHP 8.3. I have the PCNTL extension enabled, but when I try to run the following code, I get an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pcntl_rfork()

Here is the code I am using:
<?php

$pid = pcntl_rfork(RFNOWAIT|RFTSIGZMB, SIGUSR1);
if ($pid > 0) {
    // This is the parent process.
    var_dump($pid);
} else {
    // This is the child process.
    var_dump($pid);
    sleep(2); // as the child does not wait, so we see its "pid"
}
?>

I have no issues using pcntl_fork(), but I can't seem to get pcntl_rfork() to work. Based on the doc it should be available since php 8.1, which makes me wonder why this function isn't working.
Could someone explain why this error is occurring? Is pcntl_rfork() supported in PHP 8.3, or am I missing something?

I think directly with pcntl_rfork() because it doesn't exist in PHP, but your needs could potentially be met with other PHP process control mechanisms.

Did you see the notice in the manual that "This function is only available on BSD systems."?

@NicoHaase, ah,  I just realized that! I will spin up a FreeBSD instance then. Thank you for pointing that out!
